Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded with test: wts, @web/test-runner
I'm using "test": "wtr", which I presume is web testing runner, which uses mocha but not in the package.json, only in the package-lock.json I can see references to mocha.
I get this error:
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

I have tried using
done()
setTimeout()
"test": "wtr --timeout 10000"
various other things from googling the problem.
This is my test
Any ideas?
import { expect } from '@open-wc/testing';
import * as stories from '../../stories/analytical-dashboard.stories.js';

describe('test', () => {
  it('should render', async () => {
    const story = await storyFixture(stories.AnalyticalDashboard, { render });
    expect(story.shadowRoot).to.exist;
  });
});

web-test-runner-config:
export default {
  nodeResolve: true,
  files: [
    'src/**/*.test.js',
  ],
  filterBrowserLogs: log =>
    !log.args.some(
      e =>
        e?.includes?.('https://lit.dev/msg/dev-mode') ||
        e?.includes?.('https://lit.dev/msg/multiple-versions') ||
        e?.includes?.('analytics'),
    ),
  middleware: [
    backendProxyMiddleware({
      redirectTarget: '/',
      presets: [
        presets.NL,
        presets.BE
      ],
    }),
  ],
  browserStartTimeout: 60000,
};

